# Dynamic links deepLink.path empty issue

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using *firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11* I create firebase dynamic link and I can launch my app to dynamic link (https://myapp.page.link/test) I am trying to read *deepLink.path* but it is empty (not null) in Android and Ios.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();
  }

 void initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    print("---initDynamicLinks");
    if (deepLink != null) {
      toast("---deeplink---"+deepLink.path);
      print(deepLink.path);
    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
      print('--onLinkSuccess');
      if (deepLink != null) {
      toast("---deeplink---"+deepLink.path);
      print(deepLink.path);
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
  }
```

Flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale tr-TR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug your dynamic link by adding `?d=1` end of it

Example: `https://myapp.page.link/test?d=1`

After that, click on the Desktop part to see if you're redirected to the correct link. If that link has no path, then probably you won't catch it with your app.

Check your set up process to add deep link to your dynamic link carefully.

[image: firebase console screenshot]

If you've added your deep link without path, like `mycompany.com`, your path will be empty.

Use an url with path such as:

```
mycompany.com/products?item=5
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually we can handle real links path. In my case my deeplink mylink.page.link/test real link mypage.com this is not true way. I changed my real link to : mypage.com/test and then I handle "test" value